# Тёмная тема в ruSO

Tags: обсуждение, дизайн, тёмная-тема

Увидел сегодня тёмную версию SO. Планируется ли в ближайшее время добавление тёмной версии на ruSO?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично, давно этого ждал!

Comment: Я джва года ждал тёмную тему. Ура! С нетерпением жду выхода из беты.

Comment: Переходи на темную тему, у нас есть cookies!!!)))

Comment: Предложенные цветовые схемы тёмных тем просто ужасны :( Пока лучше использовать сторонние темы.

Comment: @UModeL соглашусь! Особенно при просмотре примера кода...

Answer (score 12):

У нас нет собственного дизайна, так что логично предположить, что она появится автоматически когда на SO выйдет из беты. Но это просто предположение.

Comment: Верное предположение. Сегодня уже тестировал, но вот снова убрали.

Comment: Так это не была первоапрельская шутка?

Answer (score 8):

Сейчас обкатывается [только на Stack Overflow и в Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/1991579).

Потом выкатят на MSO. А дальше...

> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

Как видно, некоторые сайты не увидят тёмной темы никогда из-за того, что у них сейчас кастомный дизай. У нас, скорей всего, появится.